# Chrome suddenly exiting without any error - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, crash

I'm running Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m on Windows 7 x64. From time to time it unexpectedly terminates. This happens most often when I open a new tab, but it's not reproducible.

There is no error whatsoever - all Chrome processes simply terminate. Sometimes there is one chrome.exe process left hanging around that I have to kill manually, sometimes not. There is no "unhandled exception" error in the Windows Application log and I don't get a JIT debug dialog, either (I have Visual Studio installed). Crash reporting is enabled in Chrome, but chrome://crashes  says "You have no recently reported crashes". However, when I restart Chrome it offers to restore tabs, because it didn't shut down properly.

How do I troubleshoot this to figure out what's causing it?

**Edit:** it still happens with all extensions disabled.

Comment: What extensions do you have installed/running?  Check those as well.

Comment: Good point about the extensions. I've disabled the 4 I had, but I doubt they're the problem.

Comment: Did you scan your RAM and also your Video Card RAM?  There might be errors.

Comment: No - what do you suggest for scanning that? Anyway, it seems unlikely to be a hardware problem, since no other application crashes like this and I don't get corrupted data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is disable all the extensions, try it out until I got a crash.

Assuming you don't get a crash since disabling all extensions, re-enable each extension one by one. If the problem comes back, you've found the culprit.

But, if you do, then there's possibly another process (perhaps a virus of some description) closing the process for you. In that instance, virus scans, removal of all start up processes you're unsure about, working from there.

Comment: I'll try, but I doubt it's the extensions. My main suspect is the virus scanner, actually (Trend Micro), but my question was really about how to properly track down the problem. I don't really want to just try random things until it seems to stop crashing.

Comment: The proper way would be to download Chromium open source, build it from scratch and debug from there. I'm not sure there's a 'proper' way to debug software that you have no source for? The only way Chrome provides to prevent you having issues is a safe mode, which would do exactly what I described above.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping there was some tool that could attach as a debugger and catch this happening, even though it's (apparently) not an unhandled exception. (I was not the one who downvoted your answer, by the way.)